Error installing npm dependencies in WSL: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir and node-gyp issues
I have this error when trying to do the npm installation.
Does anyone know what to do?
I've tried the following steps without success:

Removed node_modules and package-lock.json and ran npm install again.
Ensured I have the necessary build tools installed in WSL: python3, make, g++, and build-essential.
Configured npm to use /bin/bash as the script shell.
Updated Node.js and npm to the latest versions in WSL.
npm clear cache --force

Despite these efforts, the installation process still fails with permission errors and issues related to node-gyp. Any help or suggestions on how to resolve these errors would be greatly appreciated.
(https://i.sstatic.net/pBVZvswf.png)
